# c++ char value + "-some words here-" but error C2110

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

Normally I want a variable contain this "Hey you!".

In Javascript we can

```
var str = 'Hey' + 'you!';
```

In Web language we can

```
$str = 'Hey'.'you!';
```

but in c++

```
+ or . also cannot combine it..
```

Any ideas? I believe maybe it's just a simple thing but i really have no idea how to combine this in c++, please help...

Comment: In c++ I would use strings and not c char arrays.

Comment: google for `std::string`

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: There is you such thing like "Web language"...

Comment: @Griwes This "Web language" suspiciously looks like PHP.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, thank you, Captain, your work here is done.

Comment: @Griwes It's been a pleasure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I well understood, you just need

```
"Hey" "you"
```

(no punctuation in between)

---

Just a note about the space:

**NOTE:** in all the OP provided samples, you will get `"Heyyou"` with no spaces in between.
I just reproduced the OP request. (so adding a space in this answer is wrong, since it will not match the requirement)

Whether that can be not the real intention (he just wanted `"Hey you"`) than a space after *Hey* or before *you* is required.

Comment: Need to add the space inside one of the string literals :P

Comment: @Loggie: No, space isn't necessary

Comment: I meant in regard to the space in the requested "Hey you" :P

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, I meant as in, "Hey " "you", your answer would print "Heyyou".

Comment: @loggie: that's what exactly the OP asked.

Comment: yes you're right but when i try "Hey" str, it's not work... (str is a variable representing 'you')

Comment: @WeiKeat: in tyat case use `+`. Don't go random: read a decent book, this are basic concepts! (the things between "" are not std::strings ... that's the treacky point)